# HTML/CSS invisible margins by default, but not when using position:absolute

Tags: css, html, formatting, page-layout

Simple problem:

By default, for example, when I have a file like this:

```
<html>
  <div style="backgroundcolor:red;height:25px;width:100%;">
  </div>
</html>
```

I get a div that has margins of about 10px from the edges of the window - there is white space that basically cannot be filled even with text.

But when I do this:

```
<html>
  <div style="backgroundcolor:red;height:25px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
  </div>
</html>
```

I have it touching the edges of the window - no white space.

I want to get rid of the white space because I have a centered window that grows to 100% width and because of the invisible margin on the left, it extends farther to the right and causes the white space on both sides to be asymmetrical.

I don't want to use absolute positioning because the div I am expanding is centered, and absolute positioning in general is pretty messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` element (which is present whether you explicitly include it or not) typically has a default margin applied to it, which can be removed with this CSS:

`body { margin: 0; }`

You should also start your source with a doctype declaration, such as `<!doctype html>`, and [ensure your HTML is valid](http://validator.w3.org/), as [well as your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).